# How to send a file from Android to server using SFTP?

Tags: android, sftp

I am developing an android application which generates a report then I would like to transfer this report to a remote server using SFTP. I found some examples using the JSch's API and tried them but every time I try to send the report the app stops.

Is there any other options which I can use to send a file from android device to a server using SFTP?

Comment: You could look into AndFTP intents : http://www.lysesoft.com/products/andftp/intent.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. Had to put the code in a Thread.

Thread connectionThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {}                    });